# Changing anchor font color during a <td> hover?

Tags: css

I want to change the text color of an anchor link that sits in a table cell  on a hover. However, the change I wrote in my CSS file to accomplish this, doesn't seem to work. Could someone suggest what I might be doing incorrectly?

This is what I have in my CSS file:

```
td:hover {
    text-align: center;
    background:white;
    a:active { color:red; }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or elaborating on prdigitalson's sugggestion, if you only want that behavior on the anchors in the TD, you can go this way:

```
td:hover {text-align: center; background:white;} 
td:hover a:active {color:red; text-align: center;}
```

This says only change the color and alignment of active anchors in cells that you are hovering over. In general, it's a bad idea to change text alignment on hover.

Here's what I suggest

```
td:hover {background-color:white;}
td:hover a:active {color:red;}
```

Comment: That's good point for damn IE6, in this case though one could use `whatever` hover script as i hove posted in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

***The `:hover` won't work in IE6 which supports only links***. However, the workaround is to use [whatever hover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html)

> Most modern browsers support the
>   :hover selector for any html element.
>   This is cool, because it enables you
>   to, for instance, apply a mouseover
>   effect to table rows  using only
>   CSS. IE however, has an erratic
>   support for :hover at best, depending
>   on the particular version your visitor
>   is using.
>
> Whatever:hover is a small script that
>   automatically patches :hover, :active
>   and :focus for IE6, IE7 and IE8
>   quirks, letting you use them like you
>   would in any other browser. Version 3
>   introduces ajax support, meaning that
>   any html that gets inserted into the
>   document via javascript will also
>   trigger :hover, :active and :focus
>   styles in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those arent typos your CSS is mangled... should be:

```
td:hover {text-align: center; background:white;} 

a:active {color:red; text-align: center;} /* or whatever text-align value youre after here */
```

But keep in mind non `a` elements dont support the `:hover` pseudo element in certain browsers and versions.

Comment: Hi ... no those weren't typos. I was actually trying to accomplish what Jimmy helped me out with. Thanks for trying though ...

Answer (score 0):

```
table table td:hover {
  background: #89A6A1;
}
table table td:hover * {
  color: black !important;
}
```